# How many Non access modifiers are there in Java?

Tags: java, modifier

Can anyone tell how many Non-access Modifiers there are in Java? I have the list below, but I want to know if it is complete or if there's any other I need to add:

```
final,
abstract,
static,
strictfp,
native,
synchronized,
transient
```

Comment: You are missing `default`

Comment: You also missed `volatile`.

Comment: HI eran,Default is a access modifier know.

Comment: @RevathiMuthukrishnan No, default is not an access modifier, it marks a default implementation of an interface method.

Comment: @RevathiMuthukrishnan It was introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

1. abstract
2. static
3. final
4. synchronized
5. native
6. strictfp
7. transient
8. volatile

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to go to the source: [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).
Looking at the [keyword section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9), you can get this list:

- default
- transient
- final
- static
- strictfp
- volatile
- const
- native
- synchronized

Comment: **From that keyword list how do you the list of non-access modifier?**

Comment: You should look them up in the specs, e.g. 8.3.1 here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3. I didn't see a place in the spec where they explicitly answer this question, though. They don't distinguish between access and non-access modifiers there

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Michael Bar-Sinai's answer is correct.

The [Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class shows a total of 12 modifiers, and [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of the Java Documentation shows that there are 3 access modifiers (and a 4th nameless package-private modifier).
It follows that the **9** non-access modifiers are:

1. abstract
2. final
3. interface
4. native
5. static
6. strictfp
7. synchronized
8. transient
9. volatile

Comment: interface is not an non access modifier